# Why I have so much network responses?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ajax, api

When i'm making this request

```
Axios.get('./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
```

I have these responses:

[image]

But when I run the same code on Mac, I have no these problems

Comment: your function might get called that much time, put console.log also with it and check your console also

Comment: I'm using ComponentDidMount ...

Comment: Maybe you can try to put a console.log just before your Axios.get(), and see if the console.log is running multiple times

Comment: Is this network tab screenshot? if yes then check you have put filter to XHR only?

Comment: @monsty but what i have to put in console?

Comment: Whatever you want, you can try with "console.log('stackoverflow');" for example, and see if the "stackoverflow" message is printing multiple times in the console.

Comment: @monsty No, it apeears in cosole 1 time.

Comment: @monsty this is really strange, because when I run the same code on other computre, i have no problems.. And one more thing, the data from json doens't work on page...

Comment: Log indicates it keeps prepending multiple "\MyWebShop\" to the "phone.json". The backslash is a giveaway. Could it be some sort of Windows bug?

Comment: @terrymorse Yes, I think so. But how to fix this?

Comment: Hard to know, maybe investigate the response? `Axios.get().then(res => console.log(res.status, res.statusText, res.headers, ...)`

Comment: In this case, console is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

To prevent circular dependency, you just need to put the title of your domain.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('/MyWebShop/./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```